# Android Volley, how do I get a response and use it in another response?

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I'm used to using Volley when ony one response is needed but here the only way I can see to acheive what I want is to use 2 responses. Here's the idea :

Post the `username` from Android, in Php get the matching `user_id`, which I do like this :

```
<?php

require('dbConnect.php');

//this is me, my username in the user table
$Number = $_POST['phonenumberofuser'];

// get the username in the user table, then get the matching user_id
                $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?";
                $stmt = $con->prepare($query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $Number) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt->error);
                $stmt->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt->error);
                $result = $stmt->get_result();

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                //get the corresponding user_id in the row
            //this is the matching user_id in the user table of the user
            $user_id = $row["user_id"];
            }
```

And then in the next part of the Php script, further down, I want to use that `user_id` to get the reviews created by `user_id`, like this :

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM review WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
$results = array();

    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

        //if user_id has reviews in the db
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        //make an array called $results
                 $results[] = array(
         'category' => $row['cat_name'], 
         'name' => $row['name'],
         'phone' => $row['phone'],
         'comment' => $row['comment'],
         );
    }
    $json = json_encode($results);
echo $json;
        ?>
```

As you can see my php file echoes the `$json` which my Android Volley code takes care of, giving me `name`, `phone` and `comment` in the View.

But where do I put `user_id` in my Volley, so I can show the related reviews that `user_id` created?

Here is my `Volley` code :

```
// Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Review review = new Review();
                                review.setCategory(obj.getString("category"));

                                review.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                review.setPhone(obj.getString("phone"));
                                review.setComment(obj.getString("comment"));

                                reviewList.add(review);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }
```

Comment: Just create another volley request in the `onResponse()`?

Comment: Yes I thought of that, but how do I isolate the user_id response, so I can use it to return the required $json ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with isolate. But also I don't see what the problem is, you are able to parse the json response from your server. So I'm sure you can retrieve the user_id and use that again for another request

Comment: Yes, I am sure I can do that too. The question is how.

Comment: Back to the first comment, add another volley request in the `onResponse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of adding a new volley request in the `onResponse` of the first request

```
// change JSONArrayrequest to your appropiate request to get the user id
JsonArrayRequest userReq = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_TO_GET_USERID,
    new Response.Listener <JSONArray> () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {                
            // parse your response to get the user_id
            String user_id = <RESULT FROM PARSING YOUR RESPONSE>;
            String URL_WITH_USERID = <YOUR URL> + user_id;
            JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_WITH_USERID,

                new Response.Listener <JSONArray> () {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Review review = new Review();
                                review.setCategory(obj.getString("category"));

                                review.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                review.setPhone(obj.getString("phone"));
                                review.setComment(obj.getString("comment"));

                                reviewList.add(review);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error geting user info: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });

            // Adding request for getting user info to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error getting user: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();   
        }
    });

// Adding request for getting user_id to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(userReq);
```

Comment: Haven't quite got it working yet but your code has put me in the right direction I'm sure.